# How to return hashmap in an aidl file

Tags: android

I want hashmap as my return type for a method from aidl file.

But it is giving error as unknown return type.

My code is

```
interface IRemoteservice { 
    HashMap<String,CharSequence> getMapValues(); 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I got the solution from google groups.
And now it is working fine.
Solution is we have to declare Map in aidl file.

```
interface IRemoteservice { 
   Map getMapValues(); 
}
```

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3e6772b0041b6055#

Comment: +1 and the following thread may be relevant as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988609/2946787 + http://stackoverflow.com/a/6360359