# Android: Couldn't find import for class java.util.ArrayList in aidl file

Tags: android, service, location

I currently have a remote service which gets the users current location (this is all working fine). I now want to be able to get the users current location then add a to a list of previous locations. Here is my aidl file, where i'm having a problem :

```
import android.location.Location;
import java.util.ArrayList; //error line: couldn't find import for class java.util.ArrayList

interface ILocationService {
    Location getCurrentLocation();
    ArrayList<Location> getAllLocations();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason the return type isn't `java.util.List<Location>`?

Comment: Nope, changing ArrayList to just List fixed the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(As per my comment, which apparently fixed the problem)

Use `java.util.List<Location>` instead of `java.util.ArrayList<Location>`.

Comment: Another win for coding against interfaces rather than implementations!